# UIImage stored in CoreData into UIWebView HTML Doc

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiwebview, uiimage

I have a CoreData Entity that contains a UIImage as one of its properties. The image is "stored in external record file" if that makes a difference.

I want to display the image in a UIWebView as part of an HTML doc but I can't work out how to do it.

I can't just use the gifdata and load that data into the UIWebView as I want it to load as part of an HTML string i.e. I have other text and layout too.

I suppose I could use a placeholder file name and save the image to the directory and then delete it once the view disappears?

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: As a side note I would strongly advise against storing image data in CoreData, I did that for a project once and everything was fine until I needed existing users to migrate to a new database version.  It took **SO LONG** for the migration process and it was all because of the image data, granted I was using > 100k images...

Comment: This has nothing to do with Core Data. If you have a UIImage, the answer doesn't depend on where you got it from.

Comment: @Tom a UIImage from the image picker control is not saved anywhere on disk. It purely lives in memory. An image that has been retrieved from core data is store in persistent memory and there may have been a way of referencing where it was stored. It could have made a difference. Hence the reason for putting it there. If you're not going to offer any help then don't say anything at all.

Comment: I was trying to point out that you shouldn't waste time considering Core Data as relevant to the problem you're trying to solve. That seems useful to me, but maybe you have a different perspective. Now you've added back a tag that's still irrelevant, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you could encode the image data as base64 and embed it as a `data:` URL, but it's probably a better idea to just reference an image file.

You might want to consider storing all your images as files on disk and just reference those files from the Core Data database. Storing image data directly in the database can really hurt performance.

Comment: Cool thanks. I will take a look at these when I get back to my computer.